# Do native speakers leave out articles in slides for space?

Tags: articles, typography

Sometimes *a* and *the* take too much space in a slide, and I delete all of them to save me extra lines.

Is it a good practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing *wrong* with this: it's common practice in news headlines, and native speakers will find a well-worded sentence perfectly intelligible if the articles are removed. You must be careful about your choice of words, however, to avoid negatively affecting the clarity of your writing. It's probably not a problem as long as the text is relatively short, and presentation slides shouldn't have a lot of text, anyway.

Also, if you're going to remove any of the articles, you should probably remove *all* of them, otherwise it looks awkward, and might be interpreted as an error.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is perfectly acceptable.

You can turn

> Step 2: The user chooses a password

into

> Step 2: User chooses password

without any loss of meaning.

Comment: No loss of meaning, but I'd argue that doing so does tend to give a poor impression, as it can start to sound like breathless tabloid-speak.  The use of articles may make comprehension slightly easier, and may also eliminate ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they may leave out articles for space. Note that in addition, even besides the sapce issue, it is sometimes more natural in English to leave out articles in titles (and slides often consist of what are effectively lists of titles).